# Translation of word clutter

Tags: traducción

How can I translate

> clutter

. Not as mess but as the group of objects that conform the mess.

Comment: Welcome to the site Santiago. Now in order to receive valuable answers, could you clarify your intended usage by providing context? (what sort of objects are you asking about?, are you for a colloquial way to say it, or a  term for a more technical writing?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Permítanme pensar en voz alta:

Un "clutter" es un desorden, un relajo, un quilombo (como dirían los Argentinos), un desbarajuste, un abarrotamiento, un caos...

Así que depende de qué cosas producen ese caos:

- un abarrotamiento lo produce un gentío, una concurrencia, o mucha mercadería.
- un desorden puede ser de cosas o de pensamientos o de emociones. Si me permiten hablar salvadoreño, un cachimbo de cosas, un desvergue, un relajo. Un revuelo o agitación de emociones. Una turbación, confusión o desconcierto de pensamientos.
- el tráfico nos da un embotellamiento, una congestión, un tranque, una trabazón (insoportables, más ahora con tanta motocicleta en las ciudades latinoamericanas). Un nudo.

También encontré en internet que clutter se puede traducir como:

batiburrillo (nunca la he oído), desbaratamiento, follón, lío (por supuesto), meremágnum, revoltijo, revoltillo, olla de grillos (fig.) o reguero.

Espero no haberme salido mucho por la tangente, y que alguna de estas palabras te despierte la idea que andas buscando.

**Por tu comentario**, en el área de radares, etc., podría ser una interferencia, un estorbo, un impedimento, un bloqueo...

Comment: Es una pregunta muy específica. Lo que busco traducir es un concepto técnico del área de radares. Árboles, casas, pájaros, etc forman un conjunto de objetos "desordenados" que se suelen denominar clutter. Abarrotamiento es un buen candidato para este caso específico.

Comment: Yo consideraría la palabra maraña como apropiada para ese empleo (incluso sustantivada `emarañado de objetos fisicos —casas, árboles, cables, casas, etc`)

Comment: En wikipedia hay una entrada para este concepto en frances.https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fouillis_radar

Answer (score 0):

Desorden describes the state of disorder,  but that's really describing the mess.  The closest I can get is
*Cosas en desorden*.